# How to draw Picture on Canvas with alpha value

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

I would like to ask for experience with my problem. How can I draw `android.graphics.Picture` to canvas with specific alpha value or change alpha value to `android.graphics.Picture` itself?

Thank you for advices.